# Replace NA values with an incrementing sequence starting from the previous non-NA value

Tags: r, vector, na

I have a vector that consists of integers and NA values, and I want to replace each stretch of NA values with an incrementing sequence of integers that starts from the previous non-NA value.

This works but it's slow:

```
> v=c(NA,NA,5,NA,NA,2,8,NA)
> Reduce(\(i,j)if(is.na(j))i+1 else j,v,accumulate=T)
[1] NA NA  5  6  7  2  8  9
```

This was about ten times faster in my benchmark but it's a bit clunky:

```
> r=rle(is.na(v));w=which(r$values[-1]);s=cumsum(r$lengths);v2=v
> v2[bit::vecseq(s[w]+1,s[w+1])]=bit::vecseq(v[s[w]]+1,v[s[w]]+r$lengths[w+1]);v2
[1] NA NA  5  6  7  2  8  9
```

Is there some faster or simpler option?

Benchmark (edited to add answers to this question):

```
set.seed(0);v=sample(2e4);v[sample(2e4,1e4)]=NA
vnum=as.numeric(v)

# last observation incremented forward
loif=\(x){r=rle(is.na(x));w=which(r$values[-1]);s=cumsum(r$lengths)
  x[bit::vecseq(s[w]+1,s[w+1])]=bit::vecseq(v[s[w]]+1,v[s[w]]+r$lengths[w+1]);x}

fill_incr <- function(v){
  idx = which(complete.cases(v))
  le = length(v)

  d <- diff(c(idx, le + 1))
  v[idx[1]:le] <- sequence(d, v[complete.cases(v)])
  v
}

library(collapse)
fill_incr_collapse <- function(v){
  idx = whichNA(v, invert = TRUE)
  le = length(v)

  d <- diff(c(idx, le + 1))
  v[idx[1]:le] <- sequence(d, na_rm(v))
  v
}

# replace two `complete_cases` functions with a single `!is.na`
fill_incr2=\(x){nn=!is.na(x);w=which(nn);l=length(x);d=diff(c(w,l+1))
  x[w[1]:l]=sequence(d,x[nn]);x}

cpp11::cpp_source(,'#include "cpp11.hpp"
using namespace cpp11;
[[cpp11::register]]
doubles loif_cpp(doubles xs) {
  bool hadnonna = false;
  int n = xs.size();
  writable::doubles out(n) ;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (hadnonna && ISNA(xs[i])) {
      out[i] = out[i-1] + 1;
    } else {
      out[i] = xs[i];
      if (!ISNA(xs[i])) hadnonna = true;
    }
  }
  return out;
}')

cppFunction('NumericVector na_locf_numeric(NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  LogicalVector ina = is_na(x);

  for(int i = 1; i<n; i++) {
    if(ina[i] == TRUE) {
      x[i] = x[i-1] + 1;
    }
  }
  return x;
}')

b=microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times=100,
  Reduce(\(i,j)if(is.na(j))i+1 else j,v,accumulate=T),
  loif(v),
  fill_incr(v),
  fill_incr2(v),
  fill_incr_collapse(v),
  loif_cpp(vnum),
  na_locf_numeric(vnum))

o=sort(tapply(b$time,gsub("  +"," ",b$expr),median))
writeLines(sprintf("%.2f %s",o/min(o),names(o)))
```

The output shows the median time of a hundred runs relative to the fastest option:

```
1.00 na_locf_numeric(vnum)
2.26 loif_cpp(vnum)
9.80 fill_incr_collapse(v)
11.63 fill_incr2(v)
15.63 fill_incr(v)
20.41 loif(v)
211.83 Reduce(function(i, j) if (is.na(j)) i + 1 else j, v, accumulate = T)
```

Comment: Are you trying to save parsing time by avoiding all those pesky "spaces between expressions"? Those functions look more like a [codegolf.se] thing ...

Comment: I suspect your `loif` is going to be the best you can do until you use C++ (using either `Rcpp` or `cpp11`) for the entire thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way with `diff` and `sequence`:

```r
fill_incr <- function(v){
  idx = which(complete.cases(v))
  le = length(v)
  
  d <- diff(c(idx, le + 1))
  v[idx[1]:le] <- sequence(d, v[complete.cases(v)])
  v
}

fill_incr(v)
#[1] NA NA  5  6  7  2  8  9
```

One can also use `collapse`'s fast functions:

```r
library(collapse)
fill_incr_collapse <- function(v){
  idx = whichNA(v, invert = TRUE)
  le = length(v)
  
  d <- diff(c(idx, le + 1))
  v[idx[1]:le] <- sequence(d, na_rm(v))
  v
}
fill_incr_collapse(v)
```

Benchmark:

```r
Unit: microseconds
                  expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq      max neval
               loif(v) 1892.7 2702.95 4962.194 3509.45 4521.35 261297.5  1000
          fill_incr(v) 1693.6 2466.65 3797.575 3106.20 4044.25  32057.1  1000
 fill_incr_collapse(v)  985.2 1434.35 2844.424 1838.70 2377.05 194761.9  1000
```

Code:

```r
loif=\(x){r=rle(is.na(x));w=which(r$values[-1]);s=cumsum(r$lengths);o=x
o[bit::vecseq(s[w]+1,s[w+1])]=bit::vecseq(x[s[w]]+1,x[s[w]]+r$lengths[w+1]);o}

library(microbenchmark)
v=sample(2e4);v[sample(2e4,1e4)]=NA
b <- microbenchmark(loif(v), fill_incr(v), 
                    fill_incr_collapse(v), 
                    times = 1000)
b
```

Comment: In my benchmark `v[!is.na(v)]` was about 2.8 times slower than `collapse::na_rm(v)` and `v[complete.cases(v)]` was about 4.1 times slower. So when I replaced the two `complete.cases` functions with a single `!is.na`, it was almost as fast as the option using `collapse::na_rm`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly faster `cpp11` method, though it can likely be optimized a little and certainly be toughened up (e.g., accept integers instead of just numerics).

```r
cpp11::cpp_source(
  code = r"(
#include "cpp11.hpp"
using namespace cpp11;

[[cpp11::register]]
doubles loif_cpp(doubles xs) {
  bool hadnonna = false;
  int n = xs.size();
  writable::doubles out(n) ;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (hadnonna && ISNA(xs[i])) {
      out[i] = out[i-1] + 1;
    } else {
      out[i] = xs[i];
      if (!ISNA(xs[i])) hadnonna = true;
    }
  }
  return out;
}
)")
```

Benchmark, using `as.numeric(v)`:

```r
v=as.numeric(sample(2e4));v[sample(2e4,1e4)]=NA

bench::mark(
  Reduce = Reduce(\(i,j)if(is.na(j))i+1 else j,v,accumulate=T),
  loif = loif(v),
  fill_incr(v),
  loif_cpp = loif_cpp(v)
)
# # A tibble: 4 × 13
#   expression        min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result         memory time               gc                  
#   <bch:expr>   <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>         <list> <list>             <list>              
# 1 Reduce         13.7ms   15.1ms      61.7        NA     2.57    24     1      389ms <dbl [20,000]> <NULL> <bench_tm [25]>    <tibble [25 × 3]>   
# 2 loif          576.1µs  612.3µs    1606.         NA     2.46   654     1      407ms <dbl [20,000]> <NULL> <bench_tm [655]>   <tibble [655 × 3]>  
# 3 fill_incr(v)  589.9µs  626.1µs    1580.         NA     2.45   645     1      408ms <dbl [20,000]> <NULL> <bench_tm [646]>   <tibble [646 × 3]>  
# 4 loif_cpp      124.2µs  130.1µs    7559.         NA     0     3780     0      500ms <dbl [20,000]> <NULL> <bench_tm [3,780]> <tibble [3,780 × 3]>
```

(If you aren't familiar, `bench::mark` ensures the outputs are identical.)

Answer (score 3):

Using Rcpp you can try a fast option like this:

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('NumericVector na_locf_numeric(NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  LogicalVector ina = is_na(x);
  
  for(int i = 1; i<n; i++) {
    if(ina[i] == TRUE) {
      x[i] = x[i-1] + 1;
    }
  }
  return x;
}')
```

(Noted benchmarks added to original post.)